# Suppress error "Hostname could not be resolved"

Tags: c#

This is my code:

```
string Url = "http://illution.dk/";
WebClient Http = new WebClient();
Http.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(Url));
Http.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(GetModelTypeResponse);
```

If I run this on a machine with no internet connection an error will be thrown. "Hostname could not be resolved"

Is there any way I can remove this error message? Or check if there isn't an internet connection?

**Edit 1**

```
try
{
ComputerInfo ComputerInfoComp = new ComputerInfo();
string Url = "http://illution.dk/"
WebClient Http = new WebClient();
Http.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(Url));
Http.DownloadStringCompleted += new         DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(GetModelTypeResponse);
ComputerInfoComp = null;
}
catch (System.Net.WebException e)
{
//
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `e.Error` in your `GetModelTypeResponse` handler method. If `e.Error` is of type `WebException` then check `webException.Status` value. The value will be `WebExceptionStatus.NameResolutionFailure` in case of "Hostname could not be resolved" exception

```
public void GetModelTypeResponse(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var webException = e.Error as WebException;
    if (webException != null && 
        webException.Status == WebExceptionStatus.NameResolutionFailure)
    {
        // log
        return; // ignore
    }

    // proceed
    ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by catching that particular exception. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: So, which one should i catch?

Comment: @Fredefl when you see the exception message "Hostname could not be resolved". It will also tell you the type of the exception.

Comment: Yes it does, and it is this one: System.Net.WebException

Comment: But when i use catch (System.Net.WebException e) {/*Something*/} the error's still there

Comment: OK, then can you post your code with the exception in it? Do remember while its debugging it will still often show the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in a try...catch block. Google `exceptions` for more information.

Comment: @Fredefl: Then post your code!!! It works. I don't know what you did wrong because I can't see your code.